# How to escape the selected field that is coming from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I have a field in MySQL table that contains special characters like double quotes,single quotes and &.

How can I convert all the special characters where selecting the records from the data base using MySQL not PHP?

basically something similar to the PHP function htmlspecialchars() but in MySQL?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in MySQL directly?

Comment: There is no such thing as a special character in MySQL, there are simply characters... MySQL doesn't know or care that `&` may have some special meaning in markup or other formatting techniques, it's all just data to MySQL

Comment: Why don't you want to use PHP's `htmlspecialchars()`?  That is the correct tool for this job.  Why do you want to do this in MySQL?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: MySQL is just a storage engine. Don't try to make it into an application interface. Store the data correctly and you won't have these issues. If it's not already stored correctly, call the htmlspecialchars function on the row that contains the data, or use MySQL's create function syntax to make your own function that you can use to do this.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I though instead of running a loop to check every record in the array I would do the work in MySQL instead of PHP.

Comment: @Mike: Just use `htmlspecialchars` when you are printing the data.  It's fine to loop over the data and call that function on each value.  That's not doing anything to harm your performance.